# how to know the result type(barcode or qrcode) using zbar sdk?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, barcode, qr-code

I'm a new iphone developer, question is I want to know the sym.data 's type.  Is it codebar or qrcode?

```
- (void) readerView: (ZBarReaderView*) view
 didReadSymbols: (ZBarSymbolSet*) syms
      fromImage: (UIImage*) img 
{
//do something useful with results and display resultText in resultViewController
for(ZBarSymbol *sym in syms) {
    imageResult3.image = img; 
    **resultText3.text = sym.data;**  
    //return resultText;
                   break;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sym.typeName is what you want...

```
    resultText.text = sym.typeName;
    resultText.text =  [ resultText.text stringByAppendingString:@" - " ];
    resultText.text =  [ resultText.text stringByAppendingString:sym.data ];
```

Take a look at the ZBar documentation, at the ZBarSymbol Class Reference.